# sum values in a range of indices with O(1) complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, time-complexity, big-o

We are given a integer vector(`V[]`) and two index values, `A` and `B`. We need to sum all the integers between `V[A]` and `V[B]`.

For example,

```
V[] == {0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3}, A == 2, B == 6
Sum == V[3] + V[4] + V[5] == 4
```

Is it possible to solve with `O(1)` complexity?
I thought about using memory address operations, but I'm still not sure how it would work(something like: sum the next `(B-A)` addresses values from `&V[A]`)

Comment: How would you think that could be done?

Comment: Completely impossible. If you wanted O(1) access to range sums, you should have preprocessed your data and built a vector of prefix sums or something like that.

Comment: Usually when this question is asked, the context allows pre-processing the input. I.e. you have a class that you construct from the vector, and then a query method. The only usual requirement is that the query is O(1), but the construction can be more.

Comment: No, not without pre-processing. You could simply store a partial sum array, where S[i] = sum of elements 0->i, so your answer would be `S[B] - S[A-1]`...

Comment: So is not a service for getting other people to solve programming puzzles for you.

Comment: It cannot be done. Depends what you want do there are some algo's that helps in this situation. One is the segment tree. That in a static array works perfectly. If you have a lot of updates and query , than there is segment tree with lazy propagation... but they require memory and code, and their building requires  2n-1 operations. If is just a single sum. Better way is sum them. otherwise, these are the algo's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If preprocessing is allowed, this can be done with a secondary array.

Each element of the second array would contain the sum of the corresponding element and all preceeding elements.  This one-time preprocessing is O(n) time and O(n) space.

For example:

```
int Vsum[7];
Vsum[0] = V[0];
for (int i=1; i<7; i++) {
    Vsum[i] = Vsum[i-1] + V[i];
}
```

So with your given array, the corresponding summation array `Vsum` would contain:

```
{0, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 10}
```

Once you have this, you only need to perform 2 lookups: one for the upper bound and one for the lower bound.  So after preprocessing, getting the range sum is O(1) every time it is performed.

For the example of A==2 and B==6, you would then calculate `Vsum[B-1] - Vsum[A]` == `7 - 3` == `4`

Answer (score -3):

O(1) Space: no problem. But O(n) time will always be required for "random" numbers.

Comment: This should be a comment come on

Comment: The OP doesn't specify what kind of O(1) he's looking for. I believe that my post answers the question?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve an actual answer

Comment: @Treycos FIne if you think the question is stupid and does not deserve an answer. Why don't you just ignore it then? Does it make sense to downvote the answers because you're not fond of the question? To me it looks as if the OP does not yet grasp the meaning of the big-O notation and that there is both space and time complexity to be considered. My answer was trying to make clear that these are both part of big-O, and that the specific example does indeed have one of the two complexities as O(1) when done right.

Comment: Read above, THIS is an answer and not a comment, its precisly explained and well written

Comment: @Treycos That's not an answer IMHO since you never talk of complexity with a preprocessing step which is not taken into account. The preprocessing changes the task, and if counted it remains a O(n) time complexity.